# Change Admin View in plugin Nopcommerce

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nopcommerce

I would like to change the view `Views/Manufacturer/_CreateOrUpdate.cshtmlfrom` within my plugin.

I know that in the public site you just drop your custom view in your theme's View folder however for admin I am not sure how to override an existing view.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a fork that allow the override of views in admin zone

http://nopcommerce.codeplex.com/SourceControl/network/forks/magnuskragelund/nopCommerce

Answer (score 0):

You can put condition in existing view that if user is admin /// your code else default functionality.

> if(User.IsInRole("Admin")) { //your code } else {
>   //default code
>   }